# Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlaces

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am following an example and I am getting an error "Cannot resolve symbol GooglePlaces"

Here are the imports which are also not working, error for "se" part

```
import se.walkercrou.places.GooglePlaces;
import se.walkercrou.places.Place;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

//Browser key


//This is where error is occuring
private final GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("AIzaSyC7ai4zqvJvUIHr4fRYqZtIVNwUMtd6ZvQ");
```

I tried to resolve it by looking at dependencies but it seems to be up to date

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

Comment: what is your error . please post logcat .

Comment: Please try :
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Double checking all support libraries are up to date in the SDK manager
- Adding libraries without resources (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res)